# Buttons are not clickable inside a vertical Layout Vaadin?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, vaadin

Hi everyone I have this layout:

[image]

Here is the class MainLayout:

```
public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private VerticalLayout upperSection = new VerticalLayout();
    private HorizontalSplitPanel lowerSection = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
    private VerticalLayout menuLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    private VerticalLayout contentLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    public MainLayout() {
        upperSection.addComponent(new Label("Header"));
        menuLayout.addComponent(new Label("Menu"));
        contentLayout.addComponent(new Label("Content"));
        lowerSection.addComponent(menuLayout);
        lowerSection.addComponent(contentLayout);
        addComponent(upperSection);
        addComponent(lowerSection);
        showBorders();

        setSizeFull();
        lowerSection.setSizeFull();
        // menuLayout.setSizeFull();
        contentLayout.setSizeFull();
        setExpandRatio(lowerSection, 1);

        //lowerSection.setSplitPosition(30);
    }

    private void showBorders() {
        String style = "v-ddwrapper-over";
        setStyleName(style);
        upperSection.setStyleName(style);
        lowerSection.setStyleName(style);
        menuLayout.setStyleName(style + "-menu");
        contentLayout.setStyleName(style + "-content");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public void addMenuOption(String caption, final Component component) {
        Button button = new Button(caption);
        menuLayout.addComponent(button);

        button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                contentLayout.removeAllComponents();
                contentLayout.addComponent(component);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This layout class extends VerticalLayout and constructs the basic structure of the layout, the addMenuOption method adds a button to the left menu column and a click listener to it so that when the user clicks on the button the content layout on the right should switch its content from the current to the one bound with the button, now inside the init method of the UI:

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        MainLayout layout = new MainLayout();
        layout.addMenuOption("Option 1", new Label("Component 1"));
        layout.addMenuOption("Option 2", new Label("Component 2"));

        setContent(layout);
}
```

Actually the result I obtain is this:

[image]

But my problem is that neither of the two buttons (Option 1, Option 2) are clickable.

Where is the problem?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: I found that the problem was given by adding the "v-ddwrapper-over" style to the components. Could someone explain me why?

Answer (score 3):

You are right. Adding style "v-ddwrapper-over" to one of the components makes the buttons non-clickable. Lets take a look at definition of this style in style.css file.

```
.appName .v-ddwrapper-over:before, .so5 .v-ddwrapper-over:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
top: -1px;
right: -1px;
bottom: -1px;
left: -1px;
border: 0 solid #197de1;
}
```

What's important is the fourth line with z-index. This brings a component (more specifficaly div in DOM) to the front covering all others components with less z-index value (usually they have 0).

If you really need this style to be applied to all your components (seems weird to me) consider adding additional style to the buttons with higher z-index value.

Learn more about z-index property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: Do you think it is due to the z-index property? but how as the buttons are inside the z-indexed layout which has v-ddwrapper-over set, so as they are inside the layout should't they be clickable?

Comment: Yes, they are INSIDE layout. Imagine a kitchen table and an apple on top of it. Your table is your layout and an apple is your button. Usually you CAN grab your apple. But if you apply z-index property to table (and not to the buttons/apples), the table will be ON TOP of the apple.

You can check that using Firefox developer tools. Open your vaadin page and press F12. Find "styles editor" tab. Then, use ctrl + f to find quoted style. Change z-index property to minus 10. And see what happened? Buttons now clickable.